# MacBook cannot wake up from sleep mode after battery replacement

Tags: macos, battery, macbook, macbook-pro

I swapped my battery from my 7 year old MacBook Pro 15" Retina (Mid 2015) for an iFixit battery. So far, it also works very well. Only when I close the laptop and after a certain time the hibernation mode is activated and I then want to continue working again, the icon that I have to connect the laptop to the power supply is displayed after opening the lid (means battery is empty). If I now connect the laptop to the power supply, it can be woken up from hibernation without any problems and a full battery is displayed. I can then immediately unplug the power adapter and continue working normally with the battery.

I have already calibrated the battery several times and performed an SMC reset (at least according to the instructions, because I don't get any feedback). In the system report, the battery status is rated as Good and 8 charge cycles are displayed.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks for your help.